# PayPal payout fee are always on sender side

Tags: paypal, fee, payout

I’m using PayPal restapi for payout. What we trying to achieve is to put fee on recipient side rather than on our side. Our platform pay other for their service and it makes sense to put fee on their side.

I contacted PayPal support and they give me solution with marking payout type as ‘pay for service/good’ but this option exist only if you use PayPal dashboard.

Can I use this option but using rest api? If not, is there any way how to do payout with restapi but put fee on recipient side?

Thx in advance,
Milos

Answer (score 0):

Paypal answer it over the official channel

```
Payout api [ Case # 05802054]
Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Support. My name is Rauf, and I will be assisting you with your inquiry.

Milos, I will answer to your inquiry below:

1. Unfortunately, you cannot change the fee and put the fee on the receiver.
2. It's possible for the merchant to hold multiple currencies, but the merchant needs to enable this or contact the customer support team to add the currency in their account.

As for the conversion rate, we do have a conversion rate, but it always changes based on the market rate.

Thank you.

Sincerely
Rauf
Merchant Technical Support
PayPal
```